# Get specific data from the first item on database

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to fetch a specific data from Firebase dynamically. This is my structure:

[image: get specific data dynamically]

Getting the "Cashier" value of 2 in this image is like this:

```
FirebaseDatabase firebaseDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
final DatabaseReference databaseReferenceMyCurrentQueue = firebaseDatabase.getReference("Cashier");

databaseReferenceMyCurrentQueue.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            String queuedNumber = String.valueOf(dataSnapshot.getValue());
            currentqueue1.setText(queuedNumber);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}
});
```

How can I make the realtime fetched value of `myCurrentQueue` from 5 to 6 after deleting the first child of cashier transactions containing the myCurrentQueue of value 5? Thanks in advance.

So every delete, the realtime myCurrentQueue will change as well.

Comment: To be more clear, you want to upgrade the value of `myCurrentQueue` from 6 to 7 and after that to remove the first child?

Comment: When myCurrentQueue 5 is deleted on the firebase you want to update your textview with the next value?

Comment: @AlexMamo yes, precisely.

Comment: @KushaalSingla yes, like a working queuing system

Answer (score 1):

```
FirebaseDatabase firebaseDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();


final DatabaseReference databaseReferenceMyCurrentQueue = firebaseDatabase.getReference("CashierTransaction");

databaseReferenceMyCurrentQueue.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
          //get Data as hashMap<String, YourClass>
          //then check the lowest number and update the queue
          firebaseDatabase.getReference("Cashier").setValue(ThatNumber);

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}
});

final DatabaseReference databaseReferenceMyCurrentQueue = firebaseDatabase.getReference("Cashier");

databaseReferenceMyCurrentQueue.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            String queuedNumber = String.valueOf(dataSnapshot.getValue());
            currentqueue1.setText(queuedNumber);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}
});
```

Comment: Hi sir and thank you so much for answering. Mind sir if you can explain the code? 


                        firebaseDatabase.getReference("Cashier").setValue(ThatNumber);

why is  databaseReferenceMyCurrentQueue referenced to Cashier Transactions?
Why is the .getReference("Cashier") ? 
and what do you mean by ThatNumber? Thanks

Comment: When you delete the transaction than just received a call back on "CashierTransaction" and you are updating the textview value when any change happen on the"Cashier" node

Comment: Last question sir, how do I fetch the value of myCurrentQueue, by just firebase query? 
what will I add to

       firebaseDatabase.getReference("Cashier Transaction");

so that I can fetch only the Cashier Transaction's first child myCurrentQueue and store it on a textview?

Comment: irebaseDatabase.getReference("Cashier Transaction").orderByChild("myCurrentQueue").limitToLast(1).addValueListener